# Jboss WildFly JMS cluster - messages are sent to only one node during each run

Tags: jboss, jms

We are trying to setup a JBoss JMS cluster for load-balancing. There is a [reported issue](https://developer.jboss.org/thread/213285) on the use of MDBs for load-balancing. I am not sure if there is a workaround/fix for this, but we do want to send message to a cluster and have MDBs listening for messages addressed to specific destinations. Does anyone know a solution for this?

The other main issue is that I have configured a 2-node cluster but when I try to send messages, all messages are redirected to one node only at any given time, i.e. during another run all messages go to another node. Is this a configuration issue? If so which config value needs to be changed so that the messages are properly distributed?

Thanks,
Paddy